# Data from image pixel to corresponding vertice

Tags: javascript, image-processing, three.js, getpixel

I am trying to put my face recorded from camera and make it a little bit bumpy.

Im taking the video from camera, and putting it on a plane via texture.
From the facedetection I have a heightmap-like grayscaled image, from which i want to take pixel data and apply it to corresponding vertices, but it gets a little bet skewed.

The length of pixeldata is shorter than the amount of available vertices, so the problem is probably correct assigning.

Currently im making it like this, as seen in airtightinteractive.com/demos/js/webcammesh/:

```
function getPictureData() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('debug');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, vidWidth, vidHeight);
    var pix = imgd.data;
    return pix;
}

function getColor(x, y, data) {
    var base = (Math.floor(y) * (vidWidth + 1) + Math.floor(x)) * 4;
    var c = {
        r: data[base + 0],
        g: data[base + 1],
        b: data[base + 2],
        a: data[base + 3]
    };
    return c.r + c.g + c.b
}

function getDepth() {
    var data = getPictureData();
    //console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < vidWidth +1; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < vidHeight +1; j++) {
            cubeGeometry.vertices[j * (vidWidth + 1) + i].z = getColor(i,j,data)/55;
        }
    }
    cubeGeometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

Any idea how to match a pixel with corresponding to it vertex?

Comment: blind guess: try just `vidWidth` instead of `vidWidth + 1`.

Comment: @mrdoob thanks, I just noticed the comment. I tried earlier and indeed it helped - http://marky.pl/vu/wce/   . btw. thanks for threejs:)